# Missing gadget on EpiServer

Tags: episerver

I created one gadget in EPiServer

- DevCore.EpiCase.dll - The First
- DevCore.License Management.dll - The second

When I created the second gadget the first one disappeared of my list of gadgets.I don't understood whats happen.I don't have any error on the website and if I go to 
afetter:17003/modules/EpiCase/About/Index it's works well.I'm working with version 7.1

Some ideas about this missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

I don't know but after installing the EPi 7.5 my gadget started to get references of files in version 7.5 ( Episerver.dll, EpiServer.data.dll ) and I have tried to install my nupack on a version 7. It started to make sense when I tried to install in Epi 7.5

It makes no sense because I started my development just with version 7.0 installed on my environment. By default my references were to a GAC.

I just redefined the references to use the files of version 7.

Answer (score 1):

Did you implement the module.config file in the gadget folder?

I.e. `/modules/DevCore.EpiCase/module.config` or `/modules/DevCore.License Management/module.config` (unsure what modules oyou have)

A module.config may look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<module productName="DevCore.EpiCase">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="DevCore.EpiCase" />
  </assemblies>
</module>
```

The registration of modules in web.config is broken in some scenarios in Epi 7

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem. At moment I haven't used any module.config